# How to protect files (documents) from being downloaded

Tags: file

I have some documents on a subdirectory, for example [www.example.com/documents](http://www.example.com/documents). Inside the document folder I have files (e.g. file1.doc, file2.docx, and so on). I want users to view the files, but not to download it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to view the file the user need to download them... Maybe I don't fully get your point but I think this is not an option

Comment: I dont want the user to download it, i just want the user to see name of the files in the folder

Comment: Then don't put the files online! Just put their names on the page.

Comment: the easiest way would be to check youself the file in the folder and from there present a list of those file to the user. This way he can't do anything with those file except to know the file are there

Comment: I have written this bash script like this.                      #!/bin/bash for entry in "var/www/example.com/public_html/download" /* do  if [ -f "$entry" ]; then echo "$entry" fi done.      This works But i can't get it to Work on the browser

Answer (score 0):

(Programmer's Lore-Keepers) forgive my suggestions here...

This is a bit of a 'grey-area-programming'.

Have you considered perhaps using a technology of your choice javascript/jQuery to capture the "known" ways of copying while on your page?

Positive test : suppose the user clicks enter on a textbox and you're using jQuery to trap the enter command to then set off your trigger that is a default action to a control of your choice.

Think about this as a negative test... if the user uses key combinations such as Ctrl+A or Ctrl+P or Ctrl+S then you intercept it and interrupt their action in theory...

Other factors to consider would be how to capture the mouse drags and perhaps even right-click actions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Other factors to consider would be how to capture the mouse drags and perhaps even right-click actions.  I dont get how to do this.

Comment: I have written this bash script like this.                      #!/bin/bash for entry in "var/www/example.com/public_html/download" /* do  if [ -f "$entry" ]; then echo "$entry" fi done.

Comment: Sorry the Code is not organized, I'm doing it from iPad and it's difficult to organize it.  The Code works When i run it on the command line. But i can't get this to Work on the browser.